# Caso particular de combinatoria en C#

Tags: c#, lista

tengo una lista con requests y otra con productos y cantidades de esta, y quiero generar todas las posibles formas de asignar cada uno de los productos a las requests como combinatorias (ver adjunto 1).

Para esto lo que pense es en crear un jagged array donde las filas sean las requests y los productos las columnas (independientemente de si son de un producto o del otro) e ir llenando con 1 cuando le asigno una unidad de producto a 1 request (ver adjunto 2). De esta forma podria juntarlos despues separando X columnas por cada X cantidad que tenga un producto y unirlo.

El codigo que tengo hasta ahora es este pero no parece estar funcionando, porque no se esta generando las estructuras de el adjunto 2:

```
private void SimulateAssignations(
        List<Order> orders,
        Cart remainPurchaseCart,
        List<OrderAllocationProjection> results,
        bool[][] assigned,
        int orderIndex,
        int[][] current_assignation_p,
        int quantTotal)
    {
        
        if (EmptyCart(remainPurchaseCart) )
        {
            // Aca guardo current_assignation_p en results

            return;
        }

        for (int indexProduct = 0; indexProduct < quantTotal; indexProduct++)
        {

            if (!assigned[orderIndex][indexProduct])
            {


                // Saco un item del carrito.
                Cart newRemainCart = Cart.Clone(remainPurchaseCart);
                int productID = newRemainCart.First(it => it.Quantity > 0).ProductId;
                CartItem cartItem = newRemainCart.Find(it => it.ProductId.Equals(productID));
                cartItem.Quantity -= 1;

                for (int indexOrder = 0; indexOrder < orders.Count(); indexOrder++)
                {
                    /*CartItem cartItemOfAnOrder = current_assignation[order]
                        .Find(it => it.ProductId.Equals(productID));
                    cartItemOfAnOrder.Quantity += 1;*/

                    if (!assigned[indexOrder][indexProduct])
                    {
                        current_assignation_p[indexOrder][indexProduct] = 1;
                        assigned[indexOrder][indexProduct] = true;

                        SimulateAssignations(
                            orders,
                            newRemainCart,
                            results,
                            assigned,
                            indexOrder,
                            current_assignation_p,
                            quantTotal);

                        current_assignation_p[indexOrder][indexProduct] = 0;
                        assigned[indexOrder][indexProduct] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Algunas aclaraciones:

- OrderAllocationProjection es solo un diccionario donde voy a guardar para cada orden una asignacion de productos (carrito). No es de gran importancia, ya que el problema es la logica de generacion de combinatoria
- La funcion de EmptyCart es la condicion de corte que se fija que ya no tenga cantidades de ningun producto
- Si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo teniendo directamente la cantidad por cada order en una sola matriz tambien es valido comentarlo :)

Adjunto 1:

[image: Adjunto 1]

Adjunto 2:

[image: Adjunto 2]